# Jquery set and get href dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to set the href attribute of an a tag at run time using jQuery to be a dynamic link?  I need the link to update based on what li item it is on.  Right now it only returns/uses the last href in the list.

```
$(".testSpan a").attr("href", moreLink); - this is how I am setting my hrefs
```

*moreLink is a var that I have defined that is getting the path the link should send to.*

UPDATE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $(".mega-menu-submenu li a").each(
        function(){
            var moreLink = $(this).prop("href");
            console.log(moreLink);
            $(".page-description description").each(
                function(){
                    var desc = $(this);
                    if (desc.text().length > 140) {
                        desc.html(
                            desc.text().substring(0, 140) + "<span class='testSpan'>" + "..." + " " + "<a href='#'>" + "more \></a>" + "</span>"
                        );
                        $(".testSpan a").prop("href", moreLink);
                    };
                }
            );
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: As it is now, "moreLink" is a string, so you just set href to the actual text "moreLink" instead of a variable's value.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Use the `each` method or `attr` callback function.

Comment: @JackieChiles I just posted my HTML and sorry about the typo I added the " around moreLink and they are not in my code.

Comment: That's an improvement, but that code is JavaScript, not HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"moreLink" is not a variable, just a string.

```
$(".testSpan a").attr("href", moreLink);
```

The above code should work, but you have to set moreLink before.

Comment: This only grabs my last one in the list and not each as it goes through checking them.